# Count MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

I run a minecraft server with an add-on called Log Block which logs all things done on the server, now I am making an "admin" panel there which dives into the database and will count the total number of blocks mined and placed.

But how shall I achieve this, I'm talking about 3 million rows and counting.

Should I make a cron job to run once a day with a count(*) and then save this result, or are there better ways to achieve this?

This is the code I have at this point

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions is [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: If you have a composite index in the `lb-world` table on `(type,data,id)` (the final column of which is only necessary because you are counting over `id` instead of `*`, despite what is said in the body of your post), then your query will be extremely performant.

Comment: `COUNT(id)` should be fast anyway, especially if there are appropriate indexes (do NOT use `COUNT(*)`). But have you run the query directly in MySQL? Does it take some insane amount of time to complete? How long does it take? Do you really need to optimize or store anything?

Comment: @ryan it takes 5.8067 seconds to load the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  echo $result[0]; //Output amount of rows
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You'll get "1" no matter what you do with your original code, I've modified it so it gives the right output.

Comment: @hd1 : just one `[0]` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $result;
```

above code working fine.
another example see below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) AS myid FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $result['myid'];
```

Comment: nice attempt, though I do believe letting the database do the heavy lifting is more performant.

Comment: MySQL's COUNT() is more efficient than that.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $result[0]; //Output amount of rows


this code return the result= 1

if you want to using alias then it will showing the correct result

please see below



$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) AS mycount FROM `lb-world` WHERE type='0' AND data='0'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $result['mycount'];

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the count of the prior day, then run a cron at the start of the day to get the count. If you want more accurate counts, keep hourly or so stats. With large amounts, it might not be best to do a count every page load.

The thing you may wish to also do is use the MySQL `AS` statement to make your code a little clearer.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM...
```

This will return a column named `count` with the first row as the count. Then you can get the array (`*_fetch_array`) and get the value using:

```
$array['count']
```

This will return your desired count as `mysql_num_rows` will always return 1, since only one row was given.

**NOTICE:** do not use MySQL_* commands as they have been deprecated. Use MySQLi_* or PDO instead